# Set TextView Height programmatically from Widget

Tags: android, widget, textview, height

I am programming a widget for Android. For this I am trying to set the height of a couple of TextViews programmatically. Now, I know how to set the height of a TextView programmatically from within an Activity. I have read that you can do it like this:

```
LayoutParams layoutParams = textView.getLayoutParams();
layoutParams.height = 70;
textView.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);
```

However, how do I set the height of a TextView programmatically from within a **Widget**?

Comment: Widget uses remote views, not views. Search in that context.

Answer (score -1):

From within the widget you mean from the TextView itself then use the following method:

textView.setHeight(70)

Comment: I don't think I can use this because I am working with RemoteViews here.. right?

Comment: Have you tried using this method and if yes what happens? If you use the RelativeLayout and place your TextView within this layout then above method will work..

Comment: I don't see how I can do that. If I try to declare a TextView, I can't because the method findViewById(int) is undefined for the type Widget. Can you perhaps give an example of an implementation?

Comment: I looked around in the documentation on RemoteViews and I can't find a method for setting TextView height. http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/RemoteViews.html

Comment: Basically what I'm saying is: I know that I can set the height of a TextView with textView.setHeight(int). What I don't know is how I can do this within a Widget because I cannot declare a TextView the normal way i.e. TextView textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.something something). How do I declare a TextView within a widget so that I can use textView.setHeight(int)?

Comment: ok now I get it. So I assume you are using a different custom widget from which you need to set the height of a textview right? so I would suggest inflate that textview object and then pass this object to the widget...so in the widget you can make a method like setTextView(TextView tv). In this way you will have the object of text view which is being displayed...you can easily setHeight with this object ...i hope it helps..